# How to check if the element has child without click ( button )

Tags: javascript, html

I want to check the element has child or not using javascript, this code below is worked for me :

```
var div_coachee = document.querySelector('#search_coachee');
var input_coachee = document.querySelector('#input_coachee');

if (div_coachee.children.length >= 4) { // Check apakah ada element child di dalam coachee
    console.log(div_coachee.children.length);
} else {
    console.log("Gaada");
}
```

But the issue is, when I add some new elements on that, I checked it on console and its still not detected that the element didn't has child. So how can I solve this with real-time If I add new element on that parent, the console is count my element, Sorry for my bad English though.

Comment: To check an element in so called *"real-time"* you can use the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to listen for changes to an element's `childList`:

```js
const element = document.getElementById('div');

const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations, observer) => {
  mutations.forEach(mutation => {
      if (mutation.target.children.length >= 4) {
        console.log("4 or more!")
      } else {
        console.log("Not there yet");
      }
  });
});

observer.observe(element, {childList: true });

element.append(
  document.createElement('span'),
  document.createElement('span'),
  document.createElement('span'),
  document.createElement('span')
)
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: What does `element.append` doing? I've already had child element on myDIV, but when I deleted `element.append` , it doesn't work

Comment: `element.append()` appends children to the element. I just use it here for testing purposes. Supposedly you have some other means by which new children are added to your element.

Comment: Yup that's exactly what I mean, thanks by the way, I have my own child element but it seems the console not showing

Comment: It only starts observing after `observe()` is called. If you have added child elements before that, those will not trigger the observer. You asked about real-time monitoring, so my answer addresses that.

Comment: thank you so much sir, now Im understand what its concept.

Comment: So is there any options to make my own child get detected by the observer? I've already set the `<script>` below on my html, sorry for stupid question though